# port forwarding for a single ip - samba share

Tags: firewall, samba, port-forwarding

I have a linux box behind a Linksys firewall router. I have a Windows machine outside the firewall that would like to access Samba sharing on the linux box. The Windows machine has a static ip address.

Can I enable port forwarding on the firewall such that it will only forward requests from the ip of the one Windows machine? What is the most secure approach to enable Samba share through the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

Usually not this way, most routers let any source get at a particular port on the external IP via port forwarding, if you only want one source IP to get to that port you may have to a proper router or flash the Linksys with one of the more configurable open source firmware options if available.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up a Virtual Private Network (VPN), for example [OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/overview.html) for a secure, encrypted channel between the machines. The specific configuration will depend on your own requirements.

A good starting point is: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#samba

Answer (score -1):

Port forwarding is the safest way to accomplish what you want. With the static ip of the client you can also make rules for the firewall additionally.

Comment: How do you suggest this is done then?

Comment: Thanks for voting me down and writing nearly the same. I mentioned the optional possibility to bind access to a dedicated ip. And by the way, my 20bucks (it's a linksys) router is able to forward ports in dependency of the requesting clients ip.

Comment: I didn't vote you down and we were actually writing at the same time, there was only two mins between our posts.

Comment: And while we're at it. I missed the qualified hint for the dramatic security risk of unencrypted SAMBA connections over the internet.

Comment: Sorry, bad day her...

Comment: Sorry again, chopper3. Love, PC, Unity!